# watch for a property in vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have an async operation in parent component and need to notify child, that this operation was completed. Could I watch in child for a property change. Somewhat like:

```
new Vue({
   props:['parentReady'],
   watch:{
     parentReady(val){
       alert('parentReady prop was changed');
     }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are several ways you could do this. You could set a property in the parent when the asynchronous action was complete.

```js
console.clear()

Vue.component("child", {
  props: ["parentLoading"],
  template: `
    <h1 v-if="isParentLoading">Parent is loading...</h1>
    <h1 v-else>Parent loading complete!</h1>
  `,
  computed: {
    isParentLoading() {
      return this.parentLoading
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    loading: true
  },
  mounted() {
    setTimeout(() => this.loading = false, 2000)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.2.6/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <child :parent-loading="loading"></child>
</div>
```

You could call a method on the child.

```js
console.clear()

Vue.component("child",{
  template:`
    <h1 v-if="!loaded">Parent is loading...</h1>
    <h1 v-else>Parent loading complete!</h1>
  `,
  data(){
    return {
      loaded: false
    }
  },
  methods:{
    onLoaded(){
      this.loaded = true
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  mounted(){
    setTimeout(() => this.$refs.child.onLoaded(), 2000)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.2.6/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <child ref="child"></child>
</div>
```

You could just *watch* the property.

```js
console.clear()

Vue.component("child", {
  props: ["parentLoading"],
  template: `
    <h1 v-if="parentLoading">Parent is loading...</h1>
    <h1 v-else>Parent loading complete!</h1>
  `,
  watch: {
    parentLoading(newVal) {
      return newVal
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    loading: true
  },
  mounted() {
    setTimeout(() => this.loading = false, 2000)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.2.6/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <child :parent-loading="loading"></child>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, I was actually trying this, but made a type during camelCase to cebab-case conversion and because of that it wasn't working for me =(